# In object detection is there a function would help me to measure object size after it detected by digits Detectnet

Tags: opencv, object-detection, digits, nvidia-jetson

I have built an object detection model using digits Detectnet.

and I want to measure the size of the detected object.

I  have tested it on my Jetson TX2. and also want the measuring in the jetson after it detects, like save the diminution to a file.

the detectnet code that I am using is detectnet-camera from this tutorial [jetson-inference/detectnet-camera/detectnet-camera.cpp](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/blob/master/detectnet-camera/detectnet-camera.cpp)

which I used it to detect objects from my trained model. I also want it to measure the dimensions of the detected object.

I have searched on the internet and found this method useful
[Measuring the size of objects in an image with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) but I don't know how to integrate it with detectnet-camera.

anyone have some other way to do that or any advice on how to use that one I will be thankful for you

Comment: Do you can show an example of what should be measured? Showing as much information as possible (sourcecode snippets, running examples, error messages) could make it easier to solve this question.

Comment: thanks @nologin for your replay . i want to measure  like this pic 
https://imgur.com/4VHex32
i have used opencv for that pic from this post  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

but i want to implement something similer with my object detection model

Comment: Plz. put these information to your question/post. Use the editors functions to link or mark text or sourcecode and so on. This makes the information more readable to others. Describe what you have done so far and what you expect to get. Can you compare your expectation with sthg. that works? Do you have error messages or other config information? This should help to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @nologin thanks for your replay and I have added what I  wanted to the question.
I am still new here ^_^, I will need any kind of advice.

Comment: This is why this post was reviewed. Perhaps you are looking for sthg like that: https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/issues/160
Further more information about your code and your existing error messages would help.